# I ran `sudo kbd_mode -s` and now I can't do anything

Tags: command-line, tty

I presed <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> on Ubuntu and entered tty4 mode. After searching on Ask Ubuntu, I tried to use `sudo kbd_mode -s`  but now I can't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo kbd_mode -s` switches the keyboard into raw mode, which stops the terminal from interpreting anything you type, such as <kbd>Enter</kbd>, so is only usable non-interactively to get unprocessed key-strokes.  This is why `man kbd_mode` warns:

> Warning: changing the keyboard mode, other than between ASCII and Unicode, will  probably  make  your keyboard unusable.

Luckily there is a special key combination that can escape raw mode if it hasn't been disabled: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Otherwise, as you're not in an xterm, there is no other escape and you'll have to reboot.  Trying the rest of the *REISUB* emergency reboot sequence <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+(<kbd>E</kbd><kbd>I</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>U</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>), waiting a second or two between each letter, is the best way to do this if enough of it works.

Comment: It tells me that 'This sysrq operation is disabled'

Comment: It worked with Alt+SysRq+ REISUB. Thanks a lot for helping me‍♂️